# How to exploit dummy messages such as this

Tags: windows-8.1

*This is not a request to troubleshoot my system.*

Since a day or two, when I open a certain application, it does open, but after a few seconds I get the error dialog box below:

[image]

After OK, a second dialog appears, this time with WerFault.exe in the title and code 0xc0000142. This repeats twice, the application continues to work or crashes, depending on its mood.

I may suspect a virus attack, though my anti-virus stays quiet.

My main question is: *what can I do with such error messages*, especially the first? It gives no clue what causes the error. Is there a way to get clarifications? I am not asking to diagnose this specific problem, but rather what investigation means are available, if any?

Comment: Have you googled the error? Have you updating Adobe Reader? Try running Malwarebytes if you think it is a virus.

Comment: @burgi I am not asking to diagnose this problem. I want to know how to get more info to trace the cause. As it stands, this message is of no use.

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1437279?tstart=0 - the first result on Google

Comment: Does Event Viewer give you any more information about the error?

Comment: @CharlieRB: unfortunately, I don't see any entry with the same error code(s) :(